# Can proguard safely downgrade Java classes?

Tags: java, proguard, java1.4

Is proguard able to safely* downgrade class files from Java 6 to Java 1.4 or do I need to also run [Retroweaver](http://retroweaver.sourceforge.net/)?

I want to be able to use some compile-time features of Java 6 such as Generics and Annotations, but I unfortunately need to allow my application to run on Java 1.4.2. Is proguard able to do this by using the flag `-target 1.4`?

*By safely, I mean that it pre-verifies them and checks they will run on 1.4 so I don't have to test my application on that version every time I make a change.

Comment: I would expect your compiler to error if you attempt to compile something that relies on later functionality with `target 1.4`. Or did I misunderstand your situation?

Comment: The compiler doesn't check if certain 'functionality' (as in available classes) is available in specific versions. If you compile with a 1.6 runtime library but target 1.4 you can access 1.6 functionality at compile time but it will fail at runtime. With regard of language level features: Some features like generics (1.5) exist only at compile time, the byte code is still compatible in this regard with 1.4 even when using generics.

Comment: Yes, to be clear all of the functionality I want is compile-time only (even the annotations don't need to be present in the compiled versions) but unfortunately the Sun/Oracle Java Compilers don't let you use anything new if you specify an old target, even if it is compile-time only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProGuard's `-target` option just sets the version number in the class files. It doesn't modify or check the actual code to make sure it is compatible. The most useful application is upgrading class files to Java 1.6 (`-target 1.6`), in which case ProGuard's preverification step adds the required preverification attributes (still without changing the actual code). So yes, you'll need another tool like Retroweaver for downgrading to Java 1.4.